# Not able to use express-validator with express 3.x

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use the express-validator with express 3.0 and it gives an error when I call:

```
expressValidator = require("express-validator") 
app.use(expressValidator)

req.assert(req.body.password,'Enter Password').notEmpty()
errors = req.validationErrors()
```

I get the error:

> 500: TypeError: Object # has no method 'validationErrors'

How to use the express-validator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you install express-validator using:

```
npm install express-validator
```

You should do something like this:

```
var expressValidator = require("express-validator");
app.use(expressValidator());

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  req.assert(req.body.password,'Enter Password').notEmpty();
}
var errors = req.validationErrors();
```

Comment: the order of app.use made the difference...I move it up and down and it started working. thanks

Comment: shouldn't it also be: `app.use(expressValidator());` ??

Comment: @SoOverIt Yes... more completely... `app.use(expressValidator([options]));`

Comment: You can get rid of `app.use(expressValidator(*[option]*)` for me it gives me an error to let the `[option]`.

And for testing I use checkBody which is better than assert who has cause some issues due to Node.js `assert` conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Version issue.

```
npm i --save express-validator@4
```

then

```
node app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

version issue

```
npm i --save express-validator@4
```

and

```
npm start
```