# How to correct error as no method 'onValidationError' in validator of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I have registration form and posting the values to register function where it will validate form values with [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator).

But, when I tried with node-validator, it keeps getting error as 
**TypeError: Object # has no method 'onValidationError'**. The validator already installed in my app.

In **app.js**

```
app.post('/register', test.register);
```

In **test.js**

```
var check = require('validator').check,
sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;


exports.register = function(req, res){

    var errors = [];
    req.onValidationError(function(msg) {
        //res.render('signup', { error: msg });
        errors.push(msg);
    });
    req.check(req.body.email, 'Please enter a valid email').len(6,64).isEmail();
    req.check(req.body.username, "Username can't be empty!").isNull();

    if (errors.length) 
         return res.render(
            'register', { regErr: errors.join('\n') }
         );
}
```

How to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `node-validator` . You should be using `express-validator` for `onValidationError`

From [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) page you can see it:

> If you are using the express.js framework you can use the
>   express-validator middleware to seamlessly integrate node-validator.

```
Example http://localhost:8080/?zip=12345&foo=1&textarea=large_string

get('/', function (req, res) {
    req.onValidationError(function (msg) {
        //Redirect the user with error 'msg'
    });
```

**Additional Note:** 
The order of `app.use` is also important. Try to move `app.use(expressValidator);` up of `app.use(app.router);`. You can view the  order of `app.use` in https://github.com/justin-john/node-user-management/blob/master/app.js#L17-L18.

Comment: So there is no need to install node-validator. Should I need to uninstall node-validator from my app?

Comment: Now it gives error as `TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'assert'` on  `req.assert('email', 'required').notEmpty();`.

Comment: the order of app.use is also important Try to move 
app.use(expressValidator); up or down, you will get it working. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483554/not-able-to-use-express-validator-with-express-3-x