# Not loading "express-validator": Migration to Express 3

Tags: node.js, express

The application that I have not finished loading by including "express-validator", apparently the location where I define, use or invoke is not correct, as suggested in a comment to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483554/not-able-to-use-express-validator-with-express-3-x).

This is part of my app.js, appreciate all the suggestions:

```
var express = require('express')
    , expressValidator = require('express-validator')
    , routes = require('./routes')
    , http = require('http')
    , path = require('path');
```

...

```
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || port);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());

// The problem
app.use(expressValidator);

app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard test' }));    

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var err = req.session.error
      , msg = req.session.success;
    delete req.session.error;
    delete req.session.success;

    res.locals.message = '';
    if (err) res.locals.message = '<p class="msg error">' + err + '</p>';
    if (msg) res.locals.message = '<p class="msg success">' + msg + '</p>';
    next();
});    

app.use(app.router);
```

...

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    req.assert('email', 'Range email').len(6, 40);
    req.assert('password', 'Range password').len(6, 20);

    var errors =  req.onValidationError();

    if(errors.length == 0)
    {
```

...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [usage](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#usage), `expressValidator` is a function that will return a middleware function, so you need to explicitly call it:

```
app.use(expressValidator());
```

Comment: Thanks you very much @robertklep, I could not see my mistake.